# How to generate a random normal distribution of a fixed number of positive integers that sum up to a fixed value

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, math, random

The problem is: randomly generate *n* positive integers that sum up to a fixed value *sum* and follow a normal distribution.

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: AFAIK integers (which are discrete) can't follow a normal distribution (which is continuous)

Comment: You have to create "coin flipping tree" and cacululate results by iterating trough that tree with 50% propability left/right for e.g. 100 coins. Recommending to have several/user defineable number of layers in the tree. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lpqiGixDd0.

Comment: Or: http://math2.org/math/stat/distributions/z-dist.htm

Comment: You really need to clarify what you want. Do you want a binomial distribution, which approximates a normal distribution?

Comment: I really need to brush up my statistics. Yes, seems like I want a binomial distribution that approximates a normal distribution. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

One approach might be the following: Think of an array of (*sum* − 1) bits. Choose (*n* − 1) of them as 1, the rest 0. Now between the ones, as well as before the first one and after the last, you have runs of zero or more zeros. Take the length of each run, add 1 (to turn non-negative into positive) and you have *n* positive integers that add up to *sum*.

From an implementation point of view, you don't really need that array; all you need is the positions of the ones. Make sure they are distinct, and make sure they are in the range between 0 and *sum* − 1 exclusive.

```
def random_partition(n, sum):
  indices = [-1] + sorted(random.sample(range(sum - 1), n - 1)) + [sum - 1]
  return [indices[i + 1] - indices[i] for i in range(n)]
```

The resulting integers will *not* follow a normal distribution. As comments already indicated, a normal distribution is a continuous distribution, while you are requesting integers so you need a discrete distribution. I guess it's not exactly a binomial distribution either. But since you seem to be kind of fuzzy on what distribution you need *exactly*, maybe this is close enough to a normal distribution to serve your needs. I honestly don't know a name for the distribution you'd get; might want to check [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) about that.

Comment: This distribution is equiprobable: every possible ordered list of values which sum up to `n` has the same probability. This may well be what the OP needed.